# Set Description Problem without any of the elements enumerated/described

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A be the set of students who live within one kilometer of school and let B be the set of students who walk to classes . Describe

1) A-B

2) A∪B

How am i supposed to represent A and B?

Comment: union means "or" and $A - B$ is "A and not  B".

Comment: Represent them using words involving students, whether or not they live close to school, and whether or not they walk to class.  For example $A\cap B$ is the set of students who simultaneously live within one km of school and walk to classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write same as given in question -

A is the set of students who live within one kilometer of school.

B is the set of students who walk to classes.

Then,

1.) $A \cup B$ is the set of all students who live within one kilometer of school or who walk to classes.

2.) A - B is the set of students who live within one kilometer of school, who not walk to classes.